# Re-assign a function to the exports when import as a namespace

Tags: typescript

`a.ts`:

```
export const add = () => {
  return 'ok';
};
```

I am trying to re-assign a new `add` function like this:

```
import * as a from './a';

a.add = () => {
  return 'not ok';
};

console.log(a.add());
```

TSC throws an error:

> Cannot assign to 'add' because it is a read-only property.ts(2540)

It works fine when I use es6. How to correct the TS type of the namespace `a` so that I can re-assign a new function with the same signature?

I don't want to do this: `//@ts-ignore` and `(a as any).add = () => {}`. It may be related to ts config.

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": [
            "ES2015",
            "es2016",
            "dom",
            "es2018.promise"
        ],
        "allowJs": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "outDir": "./build",
        "rootDir": ".",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "strictFunctionTypes": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "dist",
        "docs",
        "build",
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Comment: It appears to work just fine here: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-buck-8pkdl7 with the out-of-the-box configuration.

Comment: @ZoliSzabó  No, TSC throws the same error with me in your example. Maybe related to TSConfig?

Comment: You mean simply clicking the above codesandbox link gives you the same error? and doesn't log `"not ok"` in the built-in console?

Comment: @ZoliSzabó The question is about fixing the TS type error. As I said, it may work fine at runtime, but not compile time.